# Phonegap Android REST API Cookies - ASP.NET_SessionId not coming in response headers

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I m experiencing a problem in Android Phonegap Application while logging/autheticating using a POST REST request.

My code for POST REST request is like this :-

```
$.ajax({
                url : "https://myurl.com/Test/TV1.asmx/authenticateUser",
                type : "POST",
                dataType : "json",
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data : JSON.stringify(textJson),

                success : function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    },
                error : function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                }

            });
```

Now when I try the above code on a browser or even on iOS Phonegap application I m getting two cookies ASP.NET_SessionId and .SecuAuth.
but on Android in response headers I m only getting .SecuAuth cookie and not ASP.NET_SessionId cookie.

Any Idea why that might be.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: One possibility might be that on android browser jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders() do not return non persistent cookies, dont know just a possibility. As I tried with facebook api as well and no cookies were presen in response headers.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the SessionId cookie is flagged HttpOnly, so not available to any client-side javascript.